# How to convert a huge number to Ascii using JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Anyone know how can I convert numbers like '7297118101329732781059910132689712132' without anyspace in to String?

I already did this:

```js
result = '7297118101329732781059910132689712132'
  .toString()
  .split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/)
  .map(Number)
  .map(i => String.fromCharCode(i))
  .join('');
  
console.log("Result:", result)
```

Comment: The phrase is ''Have a Nice Day''

Comment: Without a delimiter, you are sort of guessing what it would be. Is the String only going to have A-Z and a-z and spaces? Or is it any character?

Comment: A-Z its 65 to 90 and a-z its 97 to 122 and space = 32

Comment: yes, but can it have things in the extended range? Or is it just what I asked before.

Comment: That should be part of the question.

Comment: A simple regexp can match the alphabet and spaces, but if it is more than that it is a crap shoot.

Comment: The simple, dumb solution is to just capture groups of 3 if it starts with a 1: `.match(/([2-9].|1..)/g)
  .map(i => String.fromCharCode(i))
  .join('')`

Comment: the guy below already answered, sorry for the bad information my english is not so good, thanks anyway =)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just going to be simple stings, a simple regular expression can match it. If the number starts with a 1, take next two. If it is 2-9, take the next number

```js
var x = '7297118101329732781059910132689712132'
          .match(/(1\d\d|[2-9]\d)/g)
          .map(ch => String.fromCharCode(+ch))
          .join('')

console.log(x)
```

Now if you go into the extended range of characters, it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your description "*A-Z its 65 to 90 and a-z its 97 to 122 space = 32*" gives a much better base for a regex than to split into groups of three:

```js
result = '7297118101329732781059910132689712132'
  .toString()
  .match(/(32|[6-9]\d|1[0-2]\d)/g)
  .map(Number)
  .map(i => String.fromCharCode(i))
  .join('');
  
console.log("Result:", result)
```

However if you have control over the encoder, fix your data format. Not using delimiters will fail often - or use hex digits which also group into two.